# modelsim programming 60 counter (error loading design)

Tags: verilog, counter, modelsim

My code is compiling well, but it does not work when i simulate it.
It displays "error loading design". 
i think that input and output port is wrong among these modules.
but i can not find them..
please help me where the error is in my code.

```
module tb_modulo_60_binary;

  reg t_clk, reset;
  wire [7:0] t_Y;
  parameter sec = 30;

  always #(sec) t_clk = ~t_clk;
  modulo_60_binary M1 (t_Y, t_clk, reset);

  initial begin 
    t_clk = 1; reset =1; #10;
    reset = 0; #3050;
    $finish;
  end
endmodule

module modulo_60_binary(y, clk, reset);
  output [7:0] y;
  input reset, clk;
  wire TA1, TA2, TA3, JA2, JA4;
  reg [7:0] y; 

  assign TA1 = 1;
  assign TA2 = (~y[6]) && y[4];
  assign TA3 = (y[5] && y[4]) || (y[6] && y[4]);
  assign JA2 = ~y[3];
  assign JA4 = y[1]&&y[2]; 

  jk_flip_flop JK1 (1, 1, clk, y[0]);
  jk_flip_flop JK2 (JA2, 1, y[0], y[1]);
  jk_flip_flop JK3 (1, 1, y[1], y[2]);
  jk_flip_flop JK4 (JA4, 1, y[1], y[3]);
  t_flip_flop T1 (TA1, clk, y[4]);
  t_flip_flop T2 (TA2, clk, y[5]);
  t_flip_flip T3 (TA3, clk, y[6]);  
  always @(negedge clk)
  begin
    if(reset)
      y <= 8'b00000000;
    else if(y == 8'b01110011)
      y <= 8'b00000000;
  end
endmodule

module t_flip_flop(t, clk, q);
  input t, clk;
  output q;
  reg q;

  initial q=0;
  always @(negedge clk)
  begin
    if(t == 0) q <= q;
    else q <= ~q;
  end

endmodule

module jk_flip_flop(j, k, clk, Q);
  output Q;
  input j, k, clk;
  reg Q;

  always @(negedge clk)
      if({j,k} == 2'b00)  Q <= Q; 
      else if({j,k} == 2'b01)  Q <= 1'b0;
      else if({j,k} == 2'b10)  Q <= 1'b1;
      else if({j,k} == 2'b11)  Q <= ~Q;
endmodule
```

Comment: Each bit of `y` must have one driver; you have two (a module instance and a separate always​ block). Also the output of a module instance should be connected to a net type (ie `wire`). You need to rethink your rest logic

Comment: Could you tell me more details? Which part should be change? I am the first time to use verilog...

Answer (score 0):

Your `y` signal in `modulo_60_binary` is being driven in two places:

- By bit JK# and T# instances
- The reset logic that assigns all bits of `y` to zeros

Flops and comb-logic must have one clear driver. This is one of the fundamental differences between software and hardware languages.

The rest of my answer assuming the use of the JK and T flops are a design requirement. Therefore you need to delete the always block that assigns `y` to zeros and and make `y` a `wire` type.

Fixing the logic to the T flops is easy. Simply add a conditional statement. Example:

```
wire do_rst = reset || (y == 8'b01110011);
assign TA1 = do_rst ? y[4] : 1;
assign TA2 = do_rst ? y[5] : (~y[6]) && y[4];
assign TA3 = do_rst ? y[6] : (y[5] && y[4]) || (y[6] && y[4]);
```

The JK flops is harder because the output of one flop is the clock of another. I'll advice that the clock input for each JK flop should be `clk`, otherwise you are asking for a design headache for reset when it's y bits are non power of two minus one values (eg 1,3,7,15). This means you need to re-evaluate your JA# logic and add KA# logic (hint the `do_rst` from above will help). I'm not going to do the work for you beyond this.

There is the option of the asynchronous reset approach, but for this design I will advice ageist it. The reset pulse could be too short on silicon with the conditional reset for `y ==` a particular value(s), which can result in an undependable partial reset. You could add synthesis constraints/rules to keep the push wide enough, but that is just patching a brittle design. Better to design it robust at the beginning.

FYI: `y[7]` does not have a driver and the module declaration of instance T3 has a typo.